# Change password fails with "server not available"

Tags: password, high-sierra, user-account

I have a Macbook Pro running High Sierra (10.13.1). I'm trying to change my password, but I get the following error:

> The password for the account was not changed. The server is not
>   available. Change your password when your server becomes available.

The Macbook was joined to an Active Directory domain but I no longer have access to that domain. I went to the Directory Utility and clicked Unbind, which seemed to work. But I'm still unable to change the password - get the same error message.

How can I fix this?

Thank you,
Clint

Comment: This is a guess based on how things used to work and especially as a former Windows server administrator - you probably need to get back on the network with the domain and leave it properly while you can actually communicate with it (because I'm guessing it didn't actually work) and then try again. If you try to leave domain while you can't communicate with it, things break, or at least they used to.

Comment: And if you really can't, create a new user account and migrate your files over from the old one.

Comment: @Harv thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately, I no longer have access to the domain. I was hoping there would be a way to rectify without creating a new account.